# IndexError DS18B20 Temperature sensor

Tags: python, sensor, temperature, ds18b20

I have [this](http://www.adafruit.com/product/374) temperature sensor (DS18B20). I've followed the tutorial on Adafruit ([here)](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing/overview). First I had to setup some modules by doing:

```
sudo modprobe w1-gpio
sudo modprobe w1-therm
```

Then I check the serial number of the sensor (`28-000005b89af`). When I used the command `cat w1_slave` in the correct directory, it printed correctly the temperature (checked it which other thermometer):

```
a2 01 4b 46 7f ff 0e 10 d8 : crc=d8 YES
a2 01 4b 46 7f ff 0e 10 d8 t=26125 (<--- this is the temperature factor 1000)
```

But then Adafruit provides me with an [python script](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing/software) that isn't running as it should.

```
import os
import glob
import time

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28-000005b89af')[0] #serial number of my sensor
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        return temp_c, temp_f

while True:
    print(read_temp())  
    time.sleep(1)
```

When I run it as root I get an error `(line 9) device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28-000005b89af')[0] IndexError: list index out of range`.

What causes this error? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems overly complicated for the simple task it is performing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

DS18B20="/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000005d34cd2/w1_slave"

r = 0

while True:

   r += 1

   f = open(DS18B20, "r")
   data = f.read()
   f.close()

   (discard, sep, reading) = data.partition(' t=')

   t = float(reading) / 1000.0

   print("{} {:.1f}".format(r, t))

   time.sleep(3.0)
```

You could just replace DS18B20 with your devices identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. I believe when you call

```
os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')
```

in the python code, the glob tries to access the directory prior to it being created.

I added a time.sleep(5) and I have not had an issue since. 
Also I'm not over clocking.

Answer (score 0):

This number is the serial number of HIS sensor

```
28-000005b89af
```

change to

```
28*
```

and it works for me.

```
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
```