# One Wire Temperature auto setup while booting

Tags: python, boot, sensor, temperature, ds18b20

I have temperature sensor (DS18B20), also known as a 'one-wire sensor'. I've connected it to pin 4. I am using this code that someone wrote ([source](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/19884/11593)).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
DS18B20="/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000005d34cd2/w1_slave"

r = 0

while True:

   r += 1

   f = open(DS18B20, "r")
   data = f.read()
   f.close()

   (discard, sep, reading) = data.partition(' t=')

   t = float(reading) / 1000.0

   print("{} {:.1f}".format(r, t))

   time.sleep(3.0)
```

It works as it should. But everytime I reboot the Pi I have to setup the sensor by using :
`modprobe w1-gpio` and `modprobe w1-therm`. I want the Pi to do this automatically while booting up (or in the python script above). How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following lines to /etc/modules

```
w1-gpio
w1-therm
```

You'll need root privileges to do so (e.g. sudo vi /etc/modules or sudo nano /etc/modules).

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you will also need to add the following line to /boot/config.txt

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=4
```